# Split a text file on 'number of pages' criteria

Tags: java, unix, ibm-midrange

I have a large text file with around 5500 pages . i want to break it in 1000 page segment files . Actually i m working in AS400 so just want to know if there is any qshell or unix or command java that can perform this task ...Thanks! Page break is either form feed or *FCFC character !

Comment: What is a *page* in this context?  60 lines?  Formfeed?

Comment: @JamesA:It would be a form feed .. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard Unix command `split` on an IFS file.

```
split -l 60 input_filename output_prefix
```

[split - Split files into pieces](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahz/rzahzsplit.htm?)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some need to to use a QSH command, use the standard IBM i command `CPYF` with the `FROMRCD()` and `TORCD()` parameters, perhaps `NBRRCDS()`.